# How to submit suggestions to tor project?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, network-configuration, directory

I have some suggestions for Tor Browser Interface.

1. The configuration option which configures what ports tor browser connects through has been moved to a place where it does not appear when the configure button is clicked, and it only accessible after a successful connection. This could make it very difficult for people who are connecting through a firewall that only allows certain ports to configure this option, and I would suggest it is moved back.
2. The option to configure tor browser to use bridge relays has been renamed to "Tor is censored in my country". Even if in America, it could be a company, school, college, etc. firewall that is blocking the tor network (thus bridges would be useful). I would suggest ISP, firewall, etc, after the word Country.

Is there a current way to submit suggestions directly to tor project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To submit a suggestion or a feature request, then you should open a ticket on the Tor Project bug tracker at https://trac.torproject.org/

Before you do submit it, you may find that the changes to the Tor Launcher menu are already assigned to a ticket and you should get yourself up to date on the discussion and rationale behind the changes, to ensure that your suggestions are relevant or take into account the reasons for the change.